# Name of theorem that proves if an integral of a function againist all test functions in a test space is zero, then the function itself must be zero.

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, terminology, variational-analysis

I'm curious the name of a theorem in which if:
$<f,\phi>_{L_2(\Omega)} = \int_{\Omega} f\phi d\Omega = 0 \; \forall\phi \in \Phi$, then $f=0$.

It seems to me this would be a major result of functional analysis in particular.

Comment: Is it the Fundamental Lemma of the Calculus of Variations? wiki: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: Congrats for finding this theorem!